# mono develop: Assembly 'System.Deployment' not found

Tags: c#, mono

I have some simple C# application (single form) originally written in VS on win. Now i have opened it with mono develop and i got that warning and error:

```
Warning: Assembly 'System.Deployment' not found. Make sure that the assembly exists in disk. If the reference is required to build the project you may get compilation errors. (Tring.Fiscal.Primjer)
Error: The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details. (Tring.Fiscal.Primjer)
```

Any idea how to compile this app under linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The assembly `System.Deployment` is not implemented in Mono, and AFAIK there are no plans for it to be. Try to remove it from the project's references, it might build without it - if it doesn't, then you have to rewrite the code that depends on it (there shouldn't be much of it, and it will be Windows-specific anyway).

Comment: `System.Deployment` is said to be present in Mono 4.0 [1] but I get `Reference 'System.Deployment' not resolved` Any idea why? [1] http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Deployment

Comment: 'last updated: 1175 days ago' I'm afraid those pages aren't of much use anymore.